# How to prove basis for product topology?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be a collection of topological spaces.

The product topology on $$\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$$ is the topology with basis: $$\Big\{\prod_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha} \Big| U_\alpha\ \text{is open in}\  X_\alpha\ \text{for each}\ \alpha \in J\ \text{and}\ U_\alpha = X_\alpha\ \text{for all but finitely many}\ \alpha \Big\}$$

I want to prove the above collection form a basis.

Let $\prod_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha}$ be a basis element such that $U_\alpha$ is proper subset of $X_\alpha$ for finitely many indices and $U_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for the remaining indices. Also, $\prod_{\alpha \in J} V_{\alpha}$ be another basis element  such that $V_\alpha$ is proper subset of $X_\alpha$ for finitely many indices and $V_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for the remaining indices. Therefore $$\Big(\prod_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha}\Big) \cap \Big(\prod_{\alpha \in J} V_{\alpha}\Big) = \prod_{\alpha \in J} (U_{\alpha} \cap V_\alpha) = \prod_{\alpha \in J} W_{\alpha}$$ is also a basis element such that $W_\alpha$ is proper subset of $X_\alpha$ for finitely many indices and $W_\alpha = X_\alpha$  for the remaining indices. This is the second criteria for basis.

To show the first criteria for basis, we will show that for each element $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J} \in \prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$ there is a basis element containing $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J}$. Can I consider the basis element as $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$?

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, in this case any element being contained in a basic set is trivial.

Comment: A collection $B$ of subsets of a set $X$ is a base (basis) for a topology on $X$ iff $(1): \cup B=X$ (i.e. every $x\in X$is a member of at least one member of $B$), and $(2): $Whenever $b_1,b_2\in B$ and $x\in b_1\cap b_2,$ there exists $b_3\in B$ such that $x\in b_3\subseteq b_1\cap b_2$. This is easy to prove. Note that condition (2) is satisfied if $b_1\cap b_2\in B$ whenever $b_1,b_2\in B$ as we can then let $b_3=  b_1\cap b_2.$

Comment: It's the base generated by the standard product subbase $\{\pi_\alpha^{-1}[U]\mid \alpha \in J, U \subseteq X_\alpha \text{ open }\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather trivial, but I would write out the index sets in detail, to support your argument about there being only finitely many indices such $W_\alpha\neq X_\alpha$ as
$$\{\alpha | W_\alpha \neq X_\alpha\} \subseteq \{ \alpha | U_\alpha \neq X_\alpha\}\cup \{ \alpha | V_\alpha \neq X_\alpha\}$$
and the latter two sets are finite by hypothesis. The inclusion desired follows from the contrapositive: if $X_\alpha=U_\alpha=V_\alpha$ then $W_\alpha = U_\alpha \cap V_\alpha = X_\alpha$).

And yes, $\prod_{ \alpha\in J} X_\alpha$ is in your basis so feel free to use it.

Looks correct to me.